# How to use odata service to filter ip address which is of string type

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

If I have a table of logs, which has list of records containing two columns `start ip` and `end ip`

How can I use odata service in web api to filter ip address between `start ip` and `end ip`?:

Resource url : http://localhost/api/getlist?ip=192.168.1.100

So odata should perform something like this:

> Select * from logs where '192.168.1.100' between start_ip and end_ip

Thanks

Comment: Something like this `http://localhost/api/getlist?$filter=ip eq '192.168.1.100'`. Really, sounds like you need to study basic tutorial http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Comment: @T.S. i know about the basic but if you see filter operation there is no between operator and also fyi info i cannot filter ip address between start ip and end ip so o thought if there is some way if we can do customization in odata

Comment: In fact, you can customize. You can intercept odata parsed url and do whatever you want with values. But how and why would you use `between` for IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

$filter=start_IP ge '192.168.1.100' and end_IP le '192.168.1.100'